# How to solve "Error: The getter 'Platform' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterSecureStorage'." in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-secure-storage

I'm getting the following error when starting my flutter app:

```
Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_secure_storage-7.0.1/lib/flutter_secure_storage.dart:249:16: Error: The getter 'Platform' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterSecureStorage'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: I already did, but this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Platform needs to be imported:

`import 'dart:io' show Platform;`

Documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html